# Calling different setInterval() for polling multiple functions (How to handle multiple setInterval calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application in which I have to continously poll 5 different functions for which i am currently using setInterval()

The problem is most of the times the function call gets aborted and so there is an issue with sequence of execution. This is what I meant.

```
Interval=setInterval("function1()",1997);//997                

Interval=setInterval("function2()",2697); //1947, 1497

Interval=setInterval("function3()",2837); //1977

Interval=setInterval("function4()",2851);   //2177   

Interval=setInterval("function5()",2873);   //3051
```

Most of the times any of the function call is getting aborted and it affects mode of execution. I tried changing the time interval but there is still no use. is there any solution for this???

Please help...

Thanks in advance

This is a screenshot of console... This mite help to understand situation better

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use different variables for different `intervals` like,

```
Interval1 = setInterval("function1()",1997);//997                
Interval2 = setInterval("function2()",2697); //1947, 1497
Interval3 = setInterval("function3()",2837); //1977
Interval4 = setInterval("function4()",2851);   //2177   
Interval5 = setInterval("function5()",2873);   //3051
```

Comment: I have tried that out earlier but that too doesnt help. I have added a screenshot of what happens even after giving different variables for different intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Changing timer values will not help you in this case. Try assigning each setInterval to different variable:

```
        interval1 = setInterval("function1()",1997);               

        interval2 = setInterval("function2()",2697);

        interval3 = setInterval("function3()",2837); 

        interval4 = setInterval("function4()",2851);      

        interval5 = setInterval("function5()",2873);
```

Comment: I tried that out already.. but that doesnt seem to bring any change the instances which got abort kept remaining abort.

Comment: It is not that all instances are getting abort. What is meant is that, when the functions get continously polled sometimes function2 gets aborted and function 3 starts executing sometimes both function2 and function3 gets aborted and so on. It doesnt follow any particular pattern.

Comment: Then I do not understand the question. Could you please clarify it more.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of situation.

Comment: No I understand what the problem is, I just do not know what the question is. Is the question - how to prevent those functions from being aborted?

Comment: Ya exactly i want to prevent those functions getting abort. Is there a way?

Comment: I have absolutelly no idea since you did not show the code of those functions.

Comment: Those functions are for calling different jsp pages that will excute a set of db queries and return the result. I doubt whether this hav something to do with db execution time. but i am not really sure since when i execute those functions seperately they dont take much time to execute

Comment: Do you have any suggestions